# android.renderscript.renderscriptGL issue

Tags: android, android-support-library, renderscript

I've been trying to create a live wallpaper on android.
I'm using the tutorial mentioned below.
http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/getting-started-with-renderscript-on-android/
I've copied the source code and also installed the support libraries.
I however cannot find support v8 in my SDK folders located in my program files in the windows system :(
These imports work for me after i changed my project properties and added

```
renderscript.target=18

renderscript.support.mode=true

sdk.buildtools=18.1.0


import android.renderscript.Allocation;

import android.renderscript.Element;

import android.renderscript.Float2;

import android.renderscript.Matrix4f;
```

but these imports still do not work.

```
import android.renderscript.Mesh;

import android.renderscript.ProgramFragment;

import android.renderscript.ProgramFragmentFixedFunction;

import android.renderscript.ProgramRaster;

import android.renderscript.ProgramRaster.CullMode;

import android.renderscript.ProgramStore;

import android.renderscript.ProgramVertex;

android.renderscript.RenderScriptGL;
```

How do I get these to work :(. I have been trying for a while.

Write now in my sdk extras I can see support for v4 but nothing for v8 :(
so because of that import `android.support.v8` will also fail.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use the RenderScript graphics APIs with the support library. You can only use the compute functions.

Answer (score 0):

Those imports won't resolve because [all those classes are deprecated](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/renderscript/ProgramRaster.html).

Answer (score 0):

**renderscript-v8.jar** you can find by `sdk\build-tools\21.1.2\renderscript\lib`

```
dependencies {
    compile files("libs/renderscript-v8.jar")
}
```

but if you want use `RenderScriptGL`  you should compileSdkVersion -> 11~13

android {
    compileSdkVersion 13
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.carapk.noisefield"
    minSdkVersion 13
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    renderscriptTargetApi 19
    renderscriptSupportModeEnabled false
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}
```