# How to build android application with RenderScript?

Tags: android, build, renderscript

I have little problem,
When i try build application from google's source i gets these errors:
[Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X6HE4.jpg)

It's like it not reads libraries from RenderScript, but it should, becouse i was add this to build.gradle:

```
        renderscriptTargetApi 19
        renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true
```

This is oryginal source:

```
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/wallpapers/Basic/+/kitkat-release
```

And this is my from Android studio:

```
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/29006390/wallpaper.7z
```

If i'm doing something wrong please tell me, becouse this is my first try to build something with RS.

EDIT

I was changed to: "renderscriptTargetApi 14" and almost working, details in my comment below.

Answer (score 0):

RenderScriptGL (graphics) was depreciated in API 16

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/renderscript/RenderScriptGL.html

The live wallpaper project you copied from the repository contains older live wallpaper scenes which use the deprecated API. Why those remained in the repository even though deprecated is unknown.

Also see: [android.renderscript.renderscriptGL issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19760918/android-renderscript-renderscriptgl-issue)

Comment: I was changed to "renderscriptTargetApi 14" and it works, it reads these old libraries, Thank You.
  
 But now in java files refers to RenderScript (FallRS.java, GalaxyRS.java, etc.) is this error: [Screen](http://i.stack.imgur.com/RiSGI.jpg)

 So its closer to compile, but still something is missing (esp. ScriptC_ ...) 

 could anyone advise, help me to compile it?